# How to integrate drupal with elgg1.7 or 1.8 as a cms

Tags: elgg

I am currently working on elgg based site and I want to integrate drupal with elgg1.7 or 1.8  as a cms for elgg.Is this possible?If this is, please suggest how can I do this?Is there any plugin for this or any other way?

Thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

there is currently no way to integrate a drupal and an elgg website directly. However, you can set them up as 2 separate websites on different subdomains. And then add drupal/elgg modules to create the linkages you desire. It depends on what features you want, so you can have redirects to the drupal site to add the content. And then on the elgg site, you can have a module there that pulls the drupal content and displays it.

Answer (score 0):

You can  integrate Elgg with any CMS, or any DB driven sites provided you have a knowledge of the Elgg API's and general php. You can share the session between the Elgg and your external software, or use the Elgg's API to check the user login status and make the users login / register depending on that.